# There is a folder with arrow mark on it which contains my react app and it is not opening in github

Tags: git, github

[See folder with an arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVDIN.png)

I am unable to save my changes in that folder and also it on not opening in github. It has all of my react app. How can i make it trackable and can open it in github?

Comment: That is a git submodule. Looks like you have somehow added the folder as a submodule but did not commit it rightly so it is coming up there that way.

Comment: how to make it trackable in github?